# DXA 1.7 AM Module is Compatible with DXA 1.5?

Tags: dxa, audience-manager, dxa-1.5

I want to use Audience Manager Module for our DXA 1.5 (.NET Implementation)project. But as per documentation AM module is available for DXA 1.7 onward. My Question -

is  SDL.DXA.AudienceManager.Module.1.7 is compatible with DXA 1.5 ?

Please Suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audience Manager support was introduced in DXA 1.6 (see http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700) through the Audience Manager module, plus by making some changes to the DXA framework to support HTML forms and form posts.

Next to this in DXA 1.6 we started separating the Core Module making sure that the example implementation in the Core Module is optional and not a required part of the framework.

In general a DXA Module from version X, is not necessarily compatible with version Y. Of course in general the Module concept isn't changing, so it usually is possible to reuse a module from an older version on a newer version of DXA. But your question is exactly the other way around, and it is in this case NOT possible because the Audience Manager module required DXA framework changes.

If you are currently on DXA 1.5 and you need Audience Manager support, you should upgrade to DXA 1.6, so you can use the DXA 1.6 Audience Manager module.

*If you are not on SDLT ridion 2013 SP1, but on Web 8 or Web 8.5, I can advise that you upgrade to DXA 1.7, and use the 1.7 Audience Manager module (note that DXA 1.7 doesn't support SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 anymore).*

Comment: Exactly the same answer at exactly the same time! :-)

Comment: @RickPannekoek some people might actually think we coordinate this :D

Answer (score 2):

The DXA AM Module was introduced in DXA 1.6.

It is not compatible with DXA Framework 1.5, because it depends on HTML Form handling support which was introduced in DXA 1.6.

Upgrading from DXA 1.5 to DXA 1.6 (or 1.7 if you're on SDL Web 8) should be relatively easy, though. You can use the upgrade procedure described in DXA 1.7 docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17